# Why tkinter not shows the image if I pack in a command

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to pack an image for a button press(command). But, when I press the button the label shows up but it's empty

```
from tkinter import *

def y():

    x = PhotoImage(file= "M7.png")
    image = Label(root, image=x).pack()

root=Tk()
Button(root,text="IDK" ,command=y).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I want to use as a card viewer in a card game. It's a school project, that's why I use tkinter and python.
The previous queastions I not understood, that's why I asked again.

Comment: Make a reference `image.pic = x` in the function

Comment: I made it but than it shows a Traceback:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pic'
And if I press again the button it shows again an empty label, but I want to show the picture again (2 picture below each other)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `image = Label(root, image=x).pack()` will return None value because pack returns None you can compare it by printing and see the difference.

```
image = Label(root, image=x).pack() 
print(image)
image = Label(root, image=x)
print(image)
```

---

**Here is your code**

```
from tkinter import *

def y():

    x = PhotoImage(file= "M7.png")
    image = Label(root, image=x)
    image.pic = x
    image.pack()

root=Tk()
Button(root,text="IDK" ,command=y).pack()
root.mainloop()
```